# Advertising Identifier for iAd?

Tags: app-store-connect, iad

My app recently got rejected for using an Advertising Identifier, but not including the functionality for it.

The only ads I am using are iAds, so should I say select "yes" for the Advertising Identifier (IFDA) when uploading my app in iTunesConnect?

If I say no, how will they know to add the ads into my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you are only using iAd you should not select yes to the Advertising Identifier (`IFDA`) on iTunesConnect.

An IFDA is a unique identifier for your users that allows for networks to trace what actions the user takes on your application. This, in turn, allows for much more targeted advertising, but takes away from the user's privacy.

You must tell Apple if you use an IFDA, and users must be able to opt-out of being traced using an IFDA. This is to protect users' privacy.

An IFDA is only used if you would like to provide more targeted advertisements to your users. Think of it as a UUID for your user, which is shared with other applications, and allows those applications to communicate about the users actions

Comment: But how will they know I have ads?

Comment: So if I only have iAds in my code, they will know I have iAds and make sure ads display?

Comment: @JoshSchlabach Correct, an IFDA is only a unique identifier for your users. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the help dude. App now uploading to the appstore :D +1 bro